# Extra frame added after ffmpeg concat

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I have a bunch of mp4 files (h.264, 25 fps), which I want to concat. Concat file is:

```
file 'clip1.mp4'
outpoint 4

file 'clip2.mp4'
outpoint 4

file 'clip3.mp4'
outpoint 4

file 'clip4.mp4'
outpoint 4

file 'clip5.mp4'
outpoint 4
```

Then I run

`\ffmpeg -f concat -i listd.txt -vcodec copy -y testtttt.mp4`

Output is:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i listd.txt -vcodec copy -y testtttt.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002027d363080] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Input #0, concat, from 'listd.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 193 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 193 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Output #0, mp4, to 'testtttt.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 193 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 12800 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002027d36b900] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mp4 @ 000002027d376500] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 50688, current: 50688; changing to 50689. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002027d36b900] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mp4 @ 000002027d376500] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 101888, current: 101888; changing to 101889. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002027d36b900] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mp4 @ 000002027d376500] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 153088, current: 153088; changing to 153089. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002027d36b900] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mp4 @ 000002027d376500] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 204288, current: 204288; changing to 204289. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame=  505 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     661kB time=00:00:19.96 bitrate= 271.4kbits/s speed= 238x
video:656kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.823749%
```

All input files are 25 fps, so I expect 500 frames 20seconds long file in output. However I get 505.

The mediainfo looks like this:

[image]

Investigating further:

`ffprobe -select_streams v -show_frames -show_entries frame=pict_type -of csv testtttt.mp4 >1.txt`

I see that keyframes are 0, 101, 202, 303, 404.
Looks like ffmpeg adds an extra frame to each series of 100 frames.

Here's my setup (only 2MB)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fjvhcoxywhw1hb3/1080p.zip?dl=0

How do I get 500-frames, 20 seconds long file 25fps?

UPD:

I read ffmpeg docs

> This directive works best with intra frame codecs and formats where
>   all streams are tightly interleaved. For non-intra frame codecs you
>   will usually get additional packets with presentation timestamp after
>   Out point therefore the decoded content will most likely contain
>   frames after Out point too. If your streams are not tightly
>   interleaved you may not get all the packets from all streams before
>   Out point and you may only will be able to decode the earliest stream
>   until Out point.

Does that mean it's normal behaviour? Than how do I get the result I want?

Comment: Further research gave me a feeling it's not possible to fix due to the nature of h264, however video works just fine with 505 frames and it doesn't need to be fixed. The sequence of frames is IBPPPB and if I want to stop at P frame #4, it relies on B frame #6 to get decoded (which becomes #5 with smallest delay possible 1/12800). So what I wanted is not possible without transcoding.